# What's the best difficulty to farm a "Ring of Royal Grandeur"?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Ring of Royal Grandeur only drops from Act I bounty caches.  From various places online, I've heard:

- Torment I, because they're all the same
- Torment VI, because you're guaranteed a legendary drop from the cache
- Torment VIII, because you get ["added bonus"](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/20752511791#post-7) (???)
- Normal(!?!), because [almost no other legendaries drop at that level](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/20752511791#post-3) *(but the post is downvoted so it seems that might not be true)*

Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, on this patch (2.5.0), **act bonus** doesn't exit anymore. If you complete 5 bounties on any Act you will get a **Large horadric chest**, that contains the **same drops** as the Horadric and Bonus Caches together.
With this Large chest. The Ring can only be obtain on Large chest for act 1 and 4.

And now, the question about best difficulty its simple: It is true that on T6 you obtain always a legendary, but if you can do T13, do it. Can appear more legendary so more chances of obtaining the Ring. Do the **most difficulty** you can do faster. It is just lucky of getting it on the first chest or on the 100th.

On my Hardcore season, I get around 20-30 chest and 0 rings, doing the last 10 on Torment +10.

Source of changes and patch : https://us.battle.net/d3/en/game/patch-notes/

Comment: If the chance of getting a legendary is 100% at T6, what's the point of going any higher?  Won't that just slow me down?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft you get a chance at additional legendaries at higher tormnets.

Comment: I just found http://d3resource.com/difficulties/ which gives the exact probabilities of legendary for each Torment level.  It seems like T5 or T6 are the best use of my time _(possibly T7 for the two extra resources)_

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Of course you get a legendary but maybe isn't the ring and is another legendary.